# How do I get a countdown timer on JS

Tags: javascript

I have two dates with a time, and I need to make a timer after how long startTime will approach endTime. I have a sample code, but it always outputs Left time: 4h 0m 0s. Important caveat, I don't need to use the current date, I need it from the provided

```
        var endTime = '2023-09-06 19:41:55'; 
        var startTime = '2023-09-06 15:41:55';
        var targetEndTime = new Date(endTime.replace(/-/g, '/'));
        var targetTime = new Date(startTime.replace(/-/g, '/'));

        function updateCountdown() {
            
            if (targetTime < targetEndTime) {
                var timeDiff = targetEndTime - targetTime;
                var hours = Math.floor(timeDiff / (1000 * 60 * 60));
                var minutes = Math.floor((timeDiff % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
                var seconds = Math.floor((timeDiff % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

                document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'Left time: ' + hours + 'h ' + minutes + 'm ' + seconds + 's';
            } else if (targetEndTime < targetTime) {
                document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'completed.';
            } else {
                document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'expired.';
            }
        }

        setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000); 
        updateCountdown();
```

Comment: What does "I need it from the provided" mean? Since, yes, if your dates are hardcoded (as they are in your example) they will _obviously_ always display the same time difference. Either your `targetTime` or your `targetEndTime` needs to change in order to see this move...

Comment: you need to update targetTime to be the current time

Comment: Basically if you replace the specific line with this: `var timeDiff = targetEndTime - new Date;` your countdown timer works as expected, but somehow you have a requirement to not use the current time, so yeah...

Comment: How can you not count down if you do not change the time

Comment: Are you just asking how to receive user input in JavaScript?  It's not clear to me what specific problem you've encountered.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, you have to take into account the current time:

`var now = new Date().getTime();`

```js
var targetEndTime = new Date('2023-09-06 19:41:55').getTime();

function updateCountdown() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    
    if (now < targetEndTime) {
        var timeDiff = targetEndTime - now;
        var hours = Math.floor(timeDiff / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((timeDiff % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((timeDiff % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'Left time: ' + hours + 'h ' + minutes + 'm ' + seconds + 's';
    } else if (targetEndTime < targetTime) {
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'completed.';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'expired.';
    }
}

setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000);
updateCountdown();
```

```html
<div id="countdown"></div>
```